# Safe interpreters in node.js like in Tcl

Tags: node.js

Is there a node module/extension which is similar to the Tcl concept of safe interpreters ? So a "master" node.js script which is able to control several safe "slave" interpreters . "Safe" refers to not being able to access the hard disk , sockets etc (In Tcl this is controlled via policies).Another analogy would be Docker containers controlled from a master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vm` module is the node equivalent of Tcl's `interp`: https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

As a bonus, it comes with context manipulation that sort of works like `interp alias` (it replaces the global object).

Taken together, it means it's entirely possible to create a safe interp in node using vm by supplying replacements for `require()` etc. But I'm not sure if anyone's done it yet.

---

#### Additional answer:

It looks like someone's already done a lot of work on this. Check out VM2: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2 (github: https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2).